# Get count of respective id in single query Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a simple query:

```
select A,B from Table1 where id in ('');
```

which gives me output like:

```
A   B
1   X
2   V
3   R
```

Now i want to know count of value `B` in whole database:

i.e

```
A   B  CountB
1   X  3
2   V  1
3   R  2
```

Comment: How to count? Describe how to find out the 3, 1, 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to to it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT A,
             B
      FROM   Table1
      WHERE  id in ('')) t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT B,
             COUNT(B)
      FROM   Table1
      GROUP BY B) t2 ON t1.B = t2.B
```

Comment: Or should perhaps the WHERE IN condition be in both sub-queries?

Comment: He wanted the `COUNT(B)` from whole DB regardless of `id` value - that is what I gather.

Comment: You're probably right! (However, whole DB is something completely different...)

Comment: He must have meant table, at least it seems as he did :)

Answer (score 0):

May I didn't understand the question but it seems the following query should do:

```
SELECT   A,
         B,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     Table1
WHERE    .....
GROUP BY A,
         B
ORDER BY A,
         B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `group_by` if you want certain column, and then add a `count` the `id` of it to get count. So I'd do

`SELECT A,B,COUNT(B.ID) as CountB FROM Table1 WHERE id IN ('') GROUP BY B;`